# Imagens google chrome e IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Estou a fazer um site no HTML. Ao abrir a imagem, no formato PNG, no Google Chrome (abaixo) ela aparece correctamente e ao abrir no IE 11 (acima) aparece com pixeis

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<td id="Autorizado" class="Title" >  <a href="Autorizado.php" id="dialog-modal"> <img    class="overlay" id="dialog-modal" src="images/Certo.PNG" width="65%" height="20%"  style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 8px;" >
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Autorizados&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> 

  </td> 
   </td><td id="Condicionado" class="Title" >  <a href="Condicionado.php" id="dialog-modal"> <img  class="overlay" id="dialog-modal" src="images/condicionado.PNG" width="60%"  height="8%" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 8px;" >
```

Alguem me consegue ajudar com essa situação?

Comment: Estou desconfiado do formato do arquivo. Poderia disponibilizar o link para download de um dos ícones?

Comment: BOm é notável que altura/largura das imagens estão diferentes. Como está o código html? Poderia fornecer? Havia um bug no IE8 voltado a má qualidade dos PNG's. Outro ponto, este fundo da imagem é devido a transparência? Você precisa de fato de usar o alpha?

Comment: http://psicovirtuali.blogspot.pt/2011_06_01_archive.html 
a imagem esta nesse site

Comment: por acaso você está fazendo resize?

Comment: O problema é que você está escalando as imagens, e o IE por padrão não faz smoothing/antialias. Isso pode ser controlado com filtros, mas o ideal é editar a imagem em algum aplicativo.

Comment: Então terei de usar um software para reduzir o tamanho de imagem?

Comment: o que faz sua classe overlay?

Comment: Na verdade, @Bacco, o IE faz smooth, mas só fica bom para proporções pequenas de redução. Se reduzir muito o algoritmo que eles usam deixa a imagem muito *crispy*. Agora, para aumentar, sem problemas, vai ficar tão "suavizado" como em qualquer outro browser.

Comment: Olha, eu fiz o teste da imagem com tamanho original e reduzido no FF, Chrome e IE e não obtive nenhum problema de qualidade da forma que você esta exibindo em sua imagem.

Comment: e reduziste apenas no html? 
Ou usas-te algum software?

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn nos mais novos :) mas o que tem de IE desatualizado, é uma beleza... (se bem que ele mencionou IE 11, vi depois só)

Comment: eu utilizo a imagem 256x256 e depois reduzo no html width="65%" height="20%"

Comment: então provavelmente isto acontece no seu resize.

Comment: Por favor, edite a questão para conter as informações que foram adicionadas nos comentários.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está no tamanho da imagem original: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ip63yAFK9WE/TftADQnV41I/AAAAAAAAAFs/nr7HyirMdPE/s320/homehost_ok.png

Quando o IE tem que reduzir *muito* uma imagem, surgem esses artifícios, devido ao algoritmo que ele usa.

Para corrigir isso, basta redimensionar a imagem em um editor, para deixá-la mais próxima do tamanho final desejado.